# Extract Relationship Between two Entities using StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

the similar question has been asked here but i cant find any relevant answer of it so i am trying again.
I am able to get  NER and Dependency tree using the library. Now what i looking for is that i want to extract entities with the relationship between the entities. For example , "flipkart has invested in myntra" so i should be able to get entity1 as "flipkart " and entity2 as "myntra"  and "investor" as the relation .or similar kind of structure. I am not able to get correct tool for doing the same. I neee some guidelines guys, how to achieve this?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can train your own model using [Stanford relation extraction toolkit](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.shtml). The model released with the code has only a few relations: Live_In, Located_In, OrgBased_In, Work_For, and None. To train your own model, look at "Training and specifying your own model" on its webpage. The existing model is trained on a small dataset so you will go a long way if you add more training data.

If you want to extract prominent words between two entities in sentences (that is, do not want to classify them into a given set of relations), you can also look at [ReVerb](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/).

Comment: thnks @sonal , i am just looking at "roth.properties" file . i hope this is the correct file which you talking about. Each line in the file going above my head. Can you tell me by changing which properties i should be able to get tokens as "Named Entities" not as "words" . This will not solve my purpose but will take me one step up :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I would suggest first using the default model provided (the pre-trained model; you wouldn't need roth.properties) -- using the "relation" annotator in the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml).