# Customized Relationship Extraction Between two Entities Stanford NLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am looking for similar logic like from here [RelationExtraction NLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260212/nlp-to-find-relationship-between-entities)

as process explain in the answer, I am able to reach out NER and entity sinking but I am very confused with "slot filling" logic and not getting proper resources on Internet.
Here is my code sample

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,    ClassNotFoundException {
// creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution 
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// read some text in the text variable
//String text = "Mary has a little lamb. She is very cute."; // Add your text here!
String text = "Matrix Partners along with existing investors Sequoia Capital and Nexus Venture Partners has invested R100 Cr in Mumbai based food ordering app, TinyOwl. The series B funding will be used by the company to expand its geographical presence to over 50 cities, upgrade technology and enhance user experience.";
text+="In December last year, it raised $3 Mn from Sequoia Capital India and Nexus Venture Partners to deepen its presence in home market Mumbai. It was seeded by Deap Ubhi (who had earlier founded Burrp) and Sandeep Tandon.";
text+="Kunal Bahl and Rohit Bansal, were also said to be planning to invest in the company’s second round of fund raise.";
text+="Founded by Harshvardhan Mandad and Gaurav Choudhary, TinyOwl claims to have tie-up with 5,000 restaurants and processes almost 2000 orders. The app which competes with the likes of FoodPanda aims to process over 50,000 daily orders.";
text+="The top-line comes from the cut the company takes from each order placed through its app.";
text+="The startup is also planning to come with reviews which would make it a competitor of Zomato, valued at $660 Mn. Also, Zomato is entering the food ordering business to expand its offerings.";
text+="Recently another peer, Bengaluru based food delivery startup, SpoonJoy raised an undisclosed amount of funding from Sachin Bansal (Co-Founder Flipkart) and Mekin Maheshwari (CPO Flipkart), Abhishek Goyal (Founder, Tracxn) and Sahil Barua (Co-Founder, Delhivery).";
text+="-TechCrunch";

// create an empty Annotation just with the given text
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

// run all Annotators on this text
pipeline.annotate(document);

// these are all the sentences in this document
// a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
  // traversing the words in the current sentence
  // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
  for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
    // this is the text of the token
    String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
    //System.out.println(" word \n"+word);
    // this is the POS tag of the token
    String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
   // System.out.println(" pos \n"+pos);
    // this is the NER label of the token
    String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);  
    //System.out.println(" ne \n"+ne);
  }

  // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
  Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
  System.out.println(" TREE \n"+tree);

  // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
  SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
  System.out.println(" dependencies \n"+dependencies);
}

// This is the coreference link graph
// Each chain stores a set of mentions that link to each other,
// along with a method for getting the most representative mention
// Both sentence and token offsets start at 1!
Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);
System.out.println("graph \n "+graph);
}
}
```

This gives output with same entities combined now I have to take this ahead with finding relationship between these entities. Example from code string I should get in putput that "Matrix Partners" and "Sequoia Capital" has relation "investor" or similar kind of structure.
Please correct me if am wrong somewhere and lead me to correct way.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749163/extract-relationship-between-two-entities-using-stanfordcorenlp